# JBoss 5.0 giving ELExcetion

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jboss, el

I am getting ELException as mentioned below for our web app. It runs fine on Tomcat 7.0, but fails on JBoss 5.0.0-GA. I am suspecting that it is due to EL library incompatibility, but couldn't figure out the exact issue. Can somebody help me on this?

/draft_quote_preview_content.jsp(14,5) "${product.getAttributesMap().values()}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: ${product.getAttributesMap().values()}
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1150)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:820)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2359)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:839)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2359)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:839)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2359)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2415)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info:

> Since EL 2.2, which is maintained as part of Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2 (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, **JBoss AS 6**, etc), it's possible to invoke non-getter methods, if necessary with arguments.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do i call non getter methods?

Comment: `product.getAttributesMap().values()` There are two method calls here. The only thing you can do in your JSP EL version is `product.attributesMap.values` which will translate at runtime to `product.getAttributesMap().getValues()`.